# Memory Capacity and Memory Addresses

Tags: capacitor, memory, addressing, dram

According to [this site](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/hbm2e/8gb_and_16gb_hbm2e_dram.pdf), in Table2, HBM(HBM2e) has a capacity of 8Gb = 2^33 bits per channel. Here, it has a 24-bit address consisting of 4 bits from the Bank address BA[3:0], 15 bits from the Row address RA[14:0], and 5 bits from the Column address CA[5:1]. However, with 2^24 bits, it is not possible to represent the capacity of 2^33 bits.

What am I overlooking? How are the remaining 9 bits (33-24 bits) handled?

Comment: HBM is definitely not bit addressable, and probably not byte addressable either.  According to Google, it is addressed in 32 byte atoms, so that saves you 8 bits.  Looking at the datasheet, it isn't obvious to me how the 16Gbit channel configuration works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information given in the datasheet:

- MT54A8G8040A00BF — 8 channels × 64 Meg × 144 I/O
- A channel provides access to a discrete pool of memory. Channels are individually
  clocked and need not to operate synchronously. Each channel consists of an independent command and data interface comprising 214 I/O signals.

This is ECC memory (Error Checking and Correction), so this chip stores 9 bits per byte. 144 bits correspond to a usable capacity of 128 data bits, plus 16 bits used for error checking and correction.

Each channel has 64M * 144 bits, corresponding to 128 actual data bits, or 16 data bytes. These 16 ECC bytes (144 bits) get in and out of the chip in parallel, via the same number of pins.

64M (using "binary millions" of 2^20) * 16 bytes = 1GByte

8 independent channels of 1GByte each = 8GBytes

So we have the stated chip capacity.

**There are still some address bits missing though:** we have 24 total address bits, but to address these 64M 16-byte words we would need 28 bytes.

The answer seems to be in "Note 2" on page 9:

> The burst order of a BL4 burst is fixed for reads and writes, and the HBM device does not assign column address bits to distinguish between the four UI of a BL4 burst

In other words, the answer is that it doesn't care. The first page mentions "Burst Length = 4" which means fixed and not configurable. You give it an address, you get four times 128 bits (plus ECC data), in a burst, in order, and that's it.

During the digging I had to do for this answer I found a datasheet for [another HMB module from Renesas](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/low-latency-high-bandwidth-memory-datasheet-digest-edition), which seems to have enough address bits to pick which word comes first in a burst.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. 
To summarize, I understand it as follows: 
8 Channel * 2^4 Bank * 2^15 Row * 2^5 Column * 128 (=2^7) Word * 4 (=2^2) BL = 8 Channel * 8Gb 
= 8GB

Comment: That's the idea!